# Can I build an instance of a Subclass knowing some property value of that subclass

Tags: java, reflection

I have a hierarchy of so named Attribute classes, that represents single properties of my Domain Model. Each of this Attribute classes has a unique String id property.
I Also have an AttributeFactory that has a method to retrieve instances of Attribute based on id.

```
public class Attribute {
    private String id;
    private AttributeType type;
    .......
    .......

    public Attribute(String id){
       this.id=id;
    }

    public void setID(String id){
       this.id=id;
    }

    public String getID(){
       return this.id; 
    }

    .......
    .......
}
```

The interface of the Factory looks like

```
public interface IAttributeFactory {

    Attribute getAttributeByID(String id);
}
```

One implementation of this interface could have for example a HashMap as a repository of all the defined Attributes.

An example of Attribute subclass is:

```
public class ClientCode extends Attribute {

    public ClientCode(){
        super("clientCode");
        this.setType(AttributeType.CHAR_TYPE);
    }

    ........
    ........
}
```

The question is, can we using reflection or any other thing build new instances of subclasses of attributes only knowing the id of that subclasses, so implement the interface defined above, without the need to define the HashMap an add each new defined subclass to the HashMap?

Thank you in advance
Daniel

Comment: If you are going to have a subclass for every "attribute" you should look at java enumerations instead.

Answer (score 1):

If IDs are arbitrarily chosen by the client code, then it wouldn't be possible to know which ID belongs to which Attribute subclass. However, if you can somehow enforce a pattern, then yes it would be possible to instantiate subclasses by only knowing the ID. You can do that through reflection.

The sample code below how to create a new instance via reflection:

```
public void createInstanceOfSubclass(String id) {
     try {
       Class cls = Class.forName(convertIDToClassName(id));
       Class parameterTypes[] = new Class[1];
       parameterTypes[0] = String.TYPE;
       Constructor ct = cls.getConstructor(parameterTypes);

       Object arglist[] = new Object[1];
       arglist[0] = id;
       Object subclassInstance = ct.newInstance(arglist);
     }
     catch (Throwable e) {
        System.err.println(e);
     }
}
```

[It is just sample code; for example the error handling can be improved in the actual implementation.]

Basically, you will have to write the convertIDToClassName(String) method to convert an ID to the class name. Without such association, it wouldn't be possible to link the two.

Another idea is that the ID of an attribute is calculated by you; meaning that the Attribute class sets its own ID field. As a result, you directly link the subclass name and the ID field together. Therefore, it would be possible instantiate subclasses via the ID.

In any case, a personal comment would be avoid reflection and stick to creating the classes in the code (probably take out the instantiation code somewhere like in a factory class, so that your main code gets [closed for modification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle)).

Comment: Guven, thanks for you answer. The issue is that is not just find ctor for the Attribute class. I need to instantiate the corresponding subclass instead. Because not only the ID is set by the subclass, I need an instance of the subclass, not an instance of the class with the corresponding ID.

Comment: I am having a little trouble understanding the requirement I guess. Let's assume that only with the ID, you can find the name of the subclass that extends Attribute (that would be "ClientCode" in your example). The code above creates an instance of the ClientCode class. The variable 'subClassInstance' has a reference to the ClientCode class. It is an instance of the subclass and I thought that was what you wanted. You don't have to statically refer to ClientCode anywhere, it is instantiated in the code above. Let me know more about the requirements so that I can help more.

Comment: Sorry maybe I miss understand you, because the ClientCode class in my example doesn't have the Constructor ClientCode(String id). But anyway I agree with you that the issue here is to write the convertIDToClassName(id). That's the main concern of my question by the way, I want to know if I could write that conversion using reflection so I could save me the factory

Answer (score 0):

You need a factory to create an instance of specific subclass of Attribute, right? Let's do this using a typical factory pattern.

```
//TODO make this a singleton
public final class ClientFactory implements IAttributeFactory {

  public static final String CLIENT_CODE = "clientCode"; //TODO use enum 

  /** This can return a null */
  public final Attribute getAttributeByID(String id) { //TODO rename this getter to something like create
    if (null == id) return null;
    if(id == CLIENT+CODE)
      return new ClientCode(CLIENT_CODE);
    return null;
  }
}
```